# Can i set up SourceTree as external tool in Visual Studio to view log for current file?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, atlassian-sourcetree

When right clicking a file in the SourceTree log I can choose "Log selected..." and get a log view for that specific file. Is there any way I could set up SourceTree as an External Tool in Visual Studio and pass it $(ItemPath) to have it open that log view for the current file.

I'd like a way to to view the log for a specific file without having to find the file in a commit first.

If possible I'd like to also set up the "Blame selected..." option from sourcetree as an external tool for the current file.

I'm using SourceTree with Git and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I don't think SourceTree uses any command line args, so I think the answer is 'no'. I've requested a couple of command line options (submit here: https://jira.atlassian.com/) for starting SourceTree, you might suggest they add a way to use ST the way you describe...

Comment: Not a answer as such but you could use [VisualHg](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4bc8bff4-a597-4a4b-9edd-ac82e844c337) or [VisualHg2](https://bitbucket.org/lmn/visualhg2/overview) to integrate TortoiseHg into Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 means:

- either using [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), and you can easily call a log on a specific file there.
  [image: http://gitextensions.googlecode.com/files/FileHistory205.png]
- or using [VS Tools for Git extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) (included by default is VS 2013), and there you have to select the file in the explorer to see its history:
  [image: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC697666.png]
  But:
  That doesn't mean you have too "search" for that file though, since you can [synchronize the Editor with the Explorer](https://superuser.com/a/57907/141):

  Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - General - Track Active Item In Solution Explorer

(or use [this extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2010/09/16/solution-explorer-tools-when-to-sync-to-current-file-extension-11.aspx)).

That seems easier than install/declare a third-party tool.