# How do I change the GitHub URL in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, github

I know this is probably a really dumb question, but I can't figure it out. 
When you go to your branches, right click on one, and click publish, the first time it asks you for a URL and I put in the wrong one (one that doesn't even exist haha). So now whenever I try to publish a branch, it says it can't find it and I don't know how to change the URL because the option doesn't come up anymore.

Comment: Are you using Git Extensions or VS tools for Git? (the two are illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20292542/6309)

Comment: @VonC I'm using the VS Tools for Git

Answer (score 26, accepted):

2013: If you cannot change it through Visual Studio, you can at least look for it in the local config of your repo through the command line:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git config --edit
```

And you would change it there.

---

Since 2013, Git has been fully integrated to Visual Studio, and you can [access the remote git repository for a Visual Studio solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/185141/how-do-i-access-the-remote-git-repository-for-a-vi.html)

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/storage/temp/45059-test1.png]

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/storage/temp/45105-test2.png]

Comment: @bukko indeed. As I mentioned here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25107818/6309), having the git shell installed is as easy as unzipping anywhere you want the latest portable archive for msysgit: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217/PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z

Answer (score 13):

- Go to your repo directory at C or D disk.
- Change your directory settings to display hidden files from top of Windows Explorer.
- Open .git directory, then display "config" file.
- Open "config" file and change "[remote "origin"] url" row which is like; 
  "
  ...
  [remote "origin"]
  url = https://ishakkulekci-x@bitbucket.org/x/xxx.git
  ...
  "
- using new git repo address at Visual Studio

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO. This is the most straightforward way to change the GitHub URL

Answer (score 0):

- Goto Git

[image: Goto Git in Menu]

- Select Setting

[image]

- Source Control > Git Repository Setting > Remote

[image]

- Edit and Modify