# How do I run msysgit in cmder?

Tags: git, msysgit, git-bash

I was using msysgit and git-bash in cmder when I accidentally exited out of it.
Now I can't seem to figure out how to get to the unix environment I previously had.

Git bash is not recognized as a command.
All I see is the typical command window prompt displaying the `C:/User/..` rather than the `$~User`.

How would you restore the git bash session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can type the full path of your [msysgit intallation (2014, Git 1.9.z)](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) to launch a bash session.

For instance:

- `"c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-1.9.0-preview20140217\Git Bash.vbs"`: will open a new windows
- `"c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-1.9.0-preview20140217\git-bash.bat"`: will open a bash session within the current shell.

Those two scripts aren't part of `<msysgit/bin>` folder, and are not found in `%PATH%`.

As commented by [David Grayson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28128/david-grayson) and [pred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2009612/pred) below in the comments, using [`Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe) does result in an installation (in C:\Program File) which does *not* have git-bash.bat, and which rely on "Git Bash" shortcut calling `C:\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i`.

Don't use that setup. Use the much easier and more complete package [PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217/PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z) that you unzip anywhere you want and that you add to your PATH.

---

Note: with the new [Git for Windows releases (2015, Git 2.y.z)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/), that would be:

- "`c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.3.5.8-dev-preview-64-bit\git-bash.exe`": will open a bash session within the current shell.

Comment: @Shroy Great! Welcome on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also note that cmder comes with msysgit, so you can use the cmder's root\vendor\msysgit\git-bash.bat

Comment: Hm, I have git 1.9.5-preview20141217 and the batch file does not exist.  The vbs file is there, but running it from cmder is useless because it opens a new Windows which is a normal shell, not cmder.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I have PortableGit-1.9.0-preview20140217 as well (unzipped from its archived version https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217/PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z), and `git-bash.bat` *does* exist. It is important to use it, as it will set `%HOME%` for you, as opposed to calling directly `sh.exe` (which isn't even the `bash.exe`)

Comment: I keep getting this error on Windows 7. `'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` And the Git status doesn't show up.

Comment: @Pred you need to put the command in quotes `"C:\Program Files...\..."`

Comment: Same result.   `"C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\msysgit\git-bash.bat"
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
`

Comment: @Pred did you try a `cd "C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\msysgit\"` first, then `git-bash.bat`?

Comment: I don't have PortableGit; I believe that when I installed git, it downloaded it from http://git-scm.com/download/win and that version doesn't come with git-bash.bat, and it is not called "PortableGit".  That version does come with a shortcut called "Git Bash", and that shortcut executes `C:\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson ok: don't use that version. Simply unzip anywhere you want https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217/PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z. And you will good to go.

Comment: @VonC that works, but it launches me into GitBash. I was reading somewhere else, that my antivirus could be blocking that functionality. It doesn't work at work, but on my personal computer at home, it works just fine.

Comment: @Pred Ok; I can report that with the portable installation, it does work at work (McAfee anti-virus) and at home.

Comment: Should I try replacing the portable with a newer version?

Comment: @Pred you don't even have to "replace": you can test it independently: unzip (in a dedicated folder, like `c:\git1.9.5`), and make sure your PATH reference the portable Git first. That's is all that it takes to test the portable. If it isn't to your liking, remove the folder. It it is satisfactory, unintall the first Git.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try and post back.

Answer (score 33):

An easy way to get this working is to define a custom "bash" task in Cmder, and then configure it to use this task by default.

- Install [*cmder_mini*](http://gooseberrycreative.com/cmder/) (msysgit is already installed, so no need for full version)
- In Cmder, open settings: `Win + Alt + P`
- Under **Startup** > **Tasks**, add a task called `{bash}` with the following settings:

  - **Task parameters** - set the icon:

    - Either `/icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder.exe"` (for Cmder icon) or `/icon "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git.ico"` (for Git icon)
  - **Commands** - open Git's bash shell:

    - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -l -new_console:d:%USERPROFILE%`
- Under **Startup**, set startup options to **Specified name task** --> **{bash}**

...this will set Git bash as the default console in Cmder.

nb. The above obviously assumes that Git is installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git" - if that's not the case, you'll need to change the path to point to wherever Git is installed.

Comment: I know it's bad to just post thank you, but I'm extremely happy you've posted this!

Comment: It's probably equally bad to post you're welcome, but you're welcome! Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command in cmder:

```
sh -l
```

This assumes that Git's "sh" is on your PATH.  But if you installed git differently and sh is not found, then try entering the full path to it, for example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -l
```

If you want to automate this so you don't have to run sh explicitly, then go into cmder/ConEmu's settings and change the {cmd} task to have the command `sh -l` and the parameters `/dir "%HOME%"`.  Then cmder will always start up Git Bash by default, instead of Microsoft's cmd shell.