# I can't see the command prompt when using git bash in Windows

Tags: windows, git, github, command-prompt, git-bash

I can't seem to get a command prompt come up in the Git Bash Window. I use windows 8.1.

Problem I am having is when I install Git using recommended windows guide, I can't seem to get a command prompt come up in the Git Bash Window.
All I see is a underscore cursor that flashes. It doesn't move when I type any key, and nothing is written in the window.

Please can someone suggest what I might be able to do to get my command prompt back so I can type in commands.

I tried uninstalling completely using Revo Uninstaller, scanning for left over directories etc. Then reinstalling.
I tried also using gitHub and even in the GitHub shell there is no command prompt.
I tried google, and searching through stack overflow for a solution, but have found none with same issue I have.
I have tried pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> in the window to try stop any running process.
I am at a loss what to do.

Comment: You can download and install Cygwin by [following this link](https://www.cygwin.com/).  Git should run fine in Cygwin although this doesn't solve your Git bash Windows 8 problem.

Comment: Random thought: Could you try running the Git bash as an administrator?  It should not matter but anything is worth a try.

Comment: Just to clarify it is only git bash i have issue with. Ruby, Ruby on Rails, and normal WIndows Command Prompt all work properly.

Comment: Thank you Tim Biegeleisen for your 2 comments. Running as an adminstrator made no difference. I have installed Cygwin for now. At least I can use git commands here. Is strange the Git Bash command prompt doesn't appear though. Every Guide I have seen shows it working, just not on my computer. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try and install (unzip) anywhere you want the portable version of msysgit:
[PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217/PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z)

Then go to the folder where you unzip that portable git, and type

```
git-bash.bat
```

That will open a git bash, as detailed in "[How do a I run msysgit in cmder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25107818/6309)".